# Path to Action method not found?

Tags: struts-1

Why am I'm getting these **not found** errors in the **browser's console** when trying to call the method of a Struts 1 DispatchAction from a jsp/html file?:

```
http://localhost:8089/topFrame.do?method=viewAction 404 ()
http://localhost:8089/topFrame.do?method=viewAction&polnum= 404 ()
```

*I'm moving an old Struts webapp from Weblogic to Tomcat.*

What's in the **Tomcat logs**:

```
09-Aug-2017 15:58:09.497 SEVERE [http-nio-8089-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [action] in web application [/mywebapp] threw load() exception
 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path 
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.handleConfigException(ActionServlet.java:1035)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1012)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1000)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's in  **index.jsp**:

```
<%@taglib uri="WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@taglib uri="WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
        var polparam;
        function initWindow() {
            top.moveTo(150,0);
            top.resizeTo(1000,1000);

            polparam = gup( 'POLNUM' );
            if (polparam != null )
            {
              top.topFrame.location="/topFrame.do?method=viewAction&polnum="+polparam; 
            }
        }

        function gup( name ) {
            window.alert("hello2");
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
            if( results == null ) return "";  
            else    return results[1];
        }
        </script>   
    </head>

    <frameset rows="242,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" id="index" onLoad="initWindow()">    
            <noframes>
                <body bgcolor="#d341f4" text="#41f4bb">
                    Your Broswer doesn't handle frames 2.
                </body>
            </noframes>

            <frame name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize src="/topFrame.do?method=viewAction" /> 
            <frame name="mainFrame" src="blank.html" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

What's in  **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>   
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/taglibs-datetime.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/taglibs-datetime.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>   
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>WEB-INF/pagination.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/pagination.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>           
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

What's in **struts-config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">


<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="topFrameForm" type="com.aif.TopFrameForm">
            <description>This is the form bean for the entire top Frame of the webapp</description>
        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>

    <!-- Global Exceptions -->
    <global-exceptions>
    </global-exceptions>

    <!-- Global Forwards -->
    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="topFrameError" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/TopFrameError.jsp"/>
        <forward name="unknownError" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/UnknownError.jsp"/>
        <forward name="accessDenied" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/AccessDenied.jsp" />
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/topFrame" name="topFrameForm" scope="request" type="com.aif.TopFrameAction" input="WEB-INF/jsp/TopFrame.jsp" parameter="method">
            <forward name="ok" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/TopFrame.jsp" />
        </action> 
    </action-mappings>

    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />

    <!-- Message Resources -->
    <message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" null="false"/>

    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
    </plug-in>  

</struts-config>
```

What's in **com.aif.TopFrameForm**:

```
package com.aif;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm;

public class TopFrameForm extends ValidatorForm {

    private String schemeNo="";
    private String polOrClientNo="";
    private String firstName="";
    private String surname="";
    private String ddMandate="";
    private String dob="";
    private String maxResultsReached="";
    private ArrayList policies=new ArrayList();

    // Getters & setters

    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping actionMapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("validate - START");
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        errors = super.validate(actionMapping, request);

        // etc.     

        log.info("validate - END");     
        return errors;
    }
}
```

What's in **com.aif.TopFrameAction**:

```
    package com.aif;

    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
    import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

    import com.aif.Constants;

    public class TopFrameAction extends DispatchAction {

        private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog("com.aif.TopFrameAction");

        public ActionForward viewAction(    ActionMapping mapping,
                                            ActionForm    actionForm,
                                            HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) { 

            TopFrameForm form =(TopFrameForm) actionForm;
            String polno = request.getParameter("polnum");

            // etc.     
            form.setPolOrClientNo(polno);
            // etc.

            return mapping.findForward("ok");
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: @Aleksandr M - I don't understand why you removed the "struts" tag that I've added to this post. From what I understand "struts" would include all its versions and far more people follow that than "strut-1", so by removing the "struts" tag you're actually reducing the visibility of my question, or not? Thank you for helping me understand this.

Comment: The [struts] tag is rather ambiguous. IMO it can be used on questions about migration or when there are both frameworks involved. It has only 3406 questions taged with it, so visibility isn't really an issue.

Comment: I've put the "struts" tag because the problems I've had could happen in any version of struts. And may be would reach more people and inspire them to try the solutions that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. In **index.jsp**:

Remove the "/" characters from in front of all your "topFrame.do" calls:

```
top.topFrame.location = "topFrame.do?method=viewAction&polnum=" + polparam;

<frame name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize src="topFrame.do?method=viewAction" />
```

2. In **struts-config.xml**:

Change the value of the **input** attribute, in the "topFrame" action-mapping, to **input="index.jsp"** instead of **input="WEB-INF/jsp/TopFrame.jsp"**.

Add a "/" character in front of all the **paths** in **struts-config.xml**:

```
<global-forwards>
  <forward name="topFrameError" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/TopFrameError.jsp"/>
  <forward name="unknownError" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/UnknownError.jsp"/>
  <forward name="accessDenied" path="WEB-INF/jsp/error/AccessDenied.jsp" />
</global-forwards>
```

You have to use the correct DOCTYPE for the version of struts that you're using, otherwise the struts action paths won't be found:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN"
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">
```

3. **Optional:** It helps a lot to **precompile** your jsp files both to improve your webapp's performance and also to find out if there are any issues with them, instead of going back and forth as Tomcat finds issues when it loads them.

Answer (score 0):

It has been long 12 years I have touched struts so bear with me. Try appending your action path to topFrame.do in struts-config.xml.

Comment: Do you mean that I should map this action path <<path="/topFrame.do?method=viewAction">> in struts-config.xml instead of <<path="/topFrame">>? I just tried that and it does not change the result. Thank you!

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks for trying!